# Instalar un programa que he creado en java en otro ordenador

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, inno-setup

He creado en Netbeans (java) un programa basado en un formulario que conecta con una base de datos.
Quiero instalar ese programa en otro ordenador (en el que ya he instalado la base de datos y creado las tablas).
Para ello he hecho un Clean and Build (incorporando también las librerías externas), un ejecutable a partir del Jar con Launch4J y un instalable con InnoSetup.

- Si al ordenador le paso el **ejecutable**:
  Me sale un mensaje de error de Java Virtual Machine Launcher diciendo "Could not find the main class. Program will exit".
- Si al ordenador le paso el **instalable**: me dice que no es una aplicación Win32 válida.

El programa, en el ordenador en que fue diseñado, funciona correctamente. En el que me interesa, en cambio, no hay forma de instalarlo o correrlo.

¿Alguna propuesta de solución?

Answer (score 2):

El primer mensaje parece ser un problema de configuracion de Launch4J (indicar la clase inicial a ejecutar y el `classpath`), o un problema con la maquina virtual instalada (que version de Java JRE esta instalada en la maquina destino?). Intenta revisar que en el equipo de destino tenga instalado JRE de por lo menos la misma version.

Si la version de destino es mas antigua (1.6 por ejemplo) que la de compilacion (1.8) puedes asegurarte de compilar en compatibilidad con la version de destino (las clases compiladas en 1.8 difieren un poco en formato). Por ejemplo:

- Si compilas con `javac` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506795/how-to-compile-java-in-1-6-or-older-version-without-changing-the-classpath-and-p
- Si compilas con maven: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

El segundo problema es relacionado a compatibilidad. InnoSetup 6 no tiene soporte para sistemas operativos anteriores (incluidos windows XP y otros sistemas de 32bit) https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6-whatsnew.htm, si es tu caso, intenta con una version de InnoSetup mas antigua o que genere un instalador compatible de 32 bits.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu rápida respuesta.
Respecto a lo primero, en el ordenador en que diseño el programa tengo la versión 1.8.0 de java, y en el que quiero instalarlo tengo la 1.6 y no me deja actualizar a una más moderna.
Respecto a lo segundo, en efecto, la arquitectura del segundo ordenador es de 32 bits. Probaré con un innosetup más antiguo.

Comment: Para lo primero, puedes intentar compilar con un target distinto a 1.8, dependiendo del IDE donde realizas la programacion o si usas maven, gradle u otra herramienta siempre deberia haber una manera de cambiar la version de compilacion a una menor a 1.8 (pondre mas detalles)

Comment: @Stuka Con Inno setup puedes generar instaladores de 32 y 64 bits sin problemas. El inconveniente podría ser, como ya ha dicho Igor antes, si la versión del sistema operativo es menor a Windows 7, que ya no tiene soporte.